# Inclusion of smallest $\sigma$ algebras

Tags: measure-theory

I am struggling with the following problem:
Consider the measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal{B}, m)$, with $\Omega = [-\pi, \pi]$, $\mathcal{B}$ is the collection of Borel sets and $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. Let functions $f_1, f_2: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $f_1(x) = x$ and $f_2(x) = \sin(x)$. Now let $\mathcal{F}_1$ be defined as the smallest $\sigma$ algebra such that $f_1$ as a mapping from $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}_1)$ to $(\Omega, \mathcal{B})$ is measurable and $\mathcal{F}_2$ similarly. Now, I want to determine if $\mathcal{F}_1 \subset \mathcal{F}_2$ or $\mathcal{F}_1 = \mathcal{F}_2$ or $\mathcal{F}_2 \subset \mathcal{F}_1$. I think it should be $\mathcal{F}_1 = \mathcal{F}_2$, but I have no clue how to show this. Could someone help me out?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathcal F_1$ is nothing  but the a=class of sets of the  form $f_1^{-1}(E)$ where $E$ is  a Borel set in $\Omega$. Clearly this is exactly the Borel sigma algebra of $\Omega$.

Since $f_2$ is continuous it follows that $\mathcal F_2 \subset \mathcal F_1$. To prove equality it is enough to show that any Borel set in the four intervals $[-\pi, -\pi+\frac {\pi} 2), [-\pi+\frac {\pi} 2, -\pi+\pi), [-\pi+\pi, -\pi+\frac {3\pi} 2), [-\pi+\frac {3\pi} 2,-\pi+ 2\pi]$ is in $\mathcal F_2$. To prove this use the fact that $f_2$ has a continuous inverse on these intervals and hence $f_2$ maps Borel sets to Borel sets when restricted to these intervals. For example if $B$ is a Borel set in the first interval then $B=f_2^{-1}(f _2(B))$.

Comment: @RScrlli I am  not defining arcsin on these intervals. If $B$ is a Borel set in this interval I am writing $B$ as $\arcsin (sin (B))$ whcih proves that it belongs to $\mathcalF_2$.

Comment: @RScrlli There was  a typo. Thanks for  pointing it out.

Comment: Just a perhaps stupid question... Why does it follow from the fact that $f_2$ is continuous that $\mathcal{F}_2 \subset \mathcal{F}_1$?

Comment: Any continuous function is Borel to Borel measurable.